# Awk - saving variable with getline <"file" to an array?

Tags: arrays, awk, getline

I have a file:

```
var tomek mirek arek 
marta dorota ewa roman
var edek zenek ula
```

This command saves the 'var' to the array:

```
awk '/var/{split($0, a, RS); print a[1]}' file
```

I would do the same, but the getline. This command does not work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while ((getline < "file") > 0){split(/var/, a, RS); print a[1]}}'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
split(/var/, a, RS); print a[1]
```

to

```
if(/var/)
{
    split($0, a, RS)
    print a[1]
}
```